# My render isn't as detailed as the viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I am clicking "render image", it is showing me an uncomplete image in the render tab, but the render is still going on.

Image in the render view before rendering. (camera scene)

[image]

Render tab-

[image]

The rendered image is incomplete, and the render is still going on.

Render Engine- Cycles
Blender version: 3.6.1.0

Comment: as we can see in your image, you just waited for sample 9 of 4096. so Blender is indeed still rendering. The rendering is done, if there is 4096/4096. Since 4096 is a huge amount, maybe you wanna lower your sample to maybe 20 or 50 so you see quicker a result?

Comment: Compare the preview and render options in your modifier stack. Especially the subsurf modifier.

Comment: I gave this question a down-vote because of the meaningless title. It is not useful at all and it does not say anything at all about the content of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the rendering tessellation in the tessellation model options matches the preview tessellation count
hope it can help you